# nginx location host without www

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have to redirect www.example.com/docs/....pdf to trader.example.com/docs/....pdf on an existing Project. The same applies to *.biz. 
I have no Idea how can i extract the wwww-Part from $host-Variable.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com www.example.biz;

        location /docs {
                        root /data/http/example/docs;
                        rewrite ^ $scheme://trader.$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Duplicate?! The OP wanted to extract the top-level-domain portion without www part in the hostname. How can it relate to a redirect question?

Comment: By marking it as duplicate, serverfault is discouraging similar questions (I don't mean duplicate questions) and unique answers. If anyone comes across this question and this comment and if you feel that this question shouldn't be marked as duplicate, please click "reopen" link just below the tags ("nginx" and "configuration"). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to ServerFault.

You may use [map](https://nginx.org/r/map) directive to extract part of the `$host` value, like the following...

```
map $host $tld {
    default $host;
    '~^www\.(?<domain>.*)$' $domain;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com www.example.biz;

    location /docs {
        root /data/http/example/docs;
        return $scheme://trader.$tld$request_uri;
    }
}
```

`map` directive helps to extract the value of `$tld` that doesn't contain `www.` part of the URL. As an off-topic, it is not necessary to use `rewrite` statement. Since, there is no evaluation of regular expression in the above code, `return` is preferred for faster execution of statement.

Comment: Thx a lot. You made my Day :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could remove all `www` from your domains. This configuration should help.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name www.example.biz;
    return 301 $scheme://example.biz$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com example.biz;

        location /docs {
                        root /data/http/example/docs;
                        rewrite ^ $scheme://trader.$host$request_uri;
        }
}
```

**Update:** If you prefer to drop the www from multiple host names, you can add into the server block that would catch the host names (note: where possible the above is better).

```
if ($host ~* www\.(.*)) {
  set $host_without_www $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www$1 permanent; #1
  #rewrite ^ $scheme://$host_without_www$1request_uri permanent; #2
}
```

Comment: Thx for reply, but the global removement of www is in this project not a good deal. It affects many other :-). The removement should only affect on /docs

Comment: @Sirko.uhl I'm update answer.

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev Your updated answer should work as expected too. Upvoted.

Comment: Thx at both.Both sloutions work, @PothiKalimuthu solution is for my case the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I use and it works great:

```
server
{
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*)) {
        set $host_without_www $1;

        rewrite ^(.*) https://$host_without_www$1 permanent;
    }
}
```